# Confirm the meaning of Prime and Primitive in a Galois(2) polynomial.

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

[Here](http://theory.cs.uvic.ca/inf/neck/PolyInfo.html) it discusses `primality` (or more accurately `irreducibility`) and `primitivity` of polynomials in $G(2)$. More specifically it states that $x^6 + x + 1$ is `irreducible` and `primitive`.

But [here](http://www.ee.unb.ca/cgi-bin/tervo/calc.pl?num=10000001&den=1000011&f=d&e=1&p=1) I can divide $x^7 + 1$ by $x^6 + x + 1$ and get $x$ remainder $x^2+x+1$. Surely this means the the order of $x^6 + x + 1$ is at most $7$ and therefore nowhere near the required $2^6-1 = 63$ as required for primitivity.

What mistake am I making?

I guess it is my interpretation of

> The order of a polynomial $f(x)$ for which $f(0)$ is not $0$ is the smallest integer $e$ for which $f(x)$ divides $x^e+1$. A polynomial over GF(2) is primitive if it has order $2^n-1$.

Comment: Why does that mean the order is at most $7$?

Comment: @Cocopuffs - Because (in my interpretation) the order is the minimum $e$ where $p$ (the polynomial) divides $2^e+1$. See my addition.

Comment: By definition, one polynomial "divides" another if the process of division leaves no remainder.  You have shown that $x^6 + x + 1$ *does not divide* $x^7 + 1$.

Comment: Eh? But the remainder is $x^2 + x + 1$. What am I missing here?

Comment: OMG - I have it totally backwards haven't I! If there **is** a remainder it does **not** divide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the definition in the first link you provided, to see that the order of
$x^6+x+1$ is $2^6-1$, you only need to check that $(x^6+x+1)\nmid (x^{n}+1)$ for all $n<2^6-1$, and that $x^6+x+1$ does divide $x^{2^6-1}+1$. A computer check easily confirm that this is the case.

I don't see any reason why  the division of $x^7+1$ by $x^6+x+1$, giving quotient x and remainder $x^2+x+1$, would  imply that the order is at most $7$, as you claimed.

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of $\nmid$ please?

Comment: $a\nmid b$ means $a$ does not divide $b$.

Comment: But isn't that what I am saying? That $x^6+x+1$ does divide $x^7+1$ for $n$ much less than $2^6 + 1$ because $7 < 63$

Comment: +1 for your patience. Sorry for a dumb question. **If there is a remainder it does NOT divide**